# Applying Add implementation to borrowed arguments

Tags: rust

I'm trying to add two borrowed arguments of a generic type that implements `Add`. My actual method is more complicated but the essence of my problem is captured by this simplified example:

```
pub fn my_add<T: Add<Output = T>>(a: &T, b: &T) -> T
{
    a + b
}
```

I get an error message saying that `+` cannot be applied to type `&T`.

My thought is that while I've indicated that `Add` is implemented for `T`, I haven't indicated that it is implemented for `&T`. However, if I change the function declaration to `my_add<&T: Add...>` the compiler complains that it expected an ident rather than a `&`. 
I've tried putting the `&` in numerous different locations but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Comment: write `where &T: Add<Output=T>` instead, should make it compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you check the [documentation for `Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html), you'll see that it's defined as taking its arguments *by value*.  Unfortunately, you cannot simply dereference `a` and `b`, because that would require moving out of an immutable reference, which isn't allowed.

There are two ways to solve this: you can either add a `Clone` bound to `T` like so:

```
pub fn my_add<T: Add<Output = T> + Clone>(a: &T, b: &T) -> T
{
    a.clone() + b.clone()
}
```

...or you can just take `a` and `b` by value in the first place:

```
pub fn my_add<T: Add<Output = T>>(a: T, b: T) -> T
{
    a + b
}
```

As an aside, you can't add random sigils to type parameter names; if you want to so something more complex than providing basic constraints, you need a `where` clause, like so:

```
fn made_up_nonsense<T>(a: T) -> T where &T: SomeTrait, T: SomeOtherTrait {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I indicate that it is Clone, does that mean an actual memcpy will take place when addition happens? Some of the types I have in mind may be quite large and I definitely want to avoid wasteful copying.

Comment: That depends.  `Clone` simply means "a copy can be made", but says nothing about the complexity.  If you can, it's best to go with the second option; then, at least, any copies that need to be made are explicit to the caller.  Also, I just realised that the `clone`s in the second example were entirely incorrect; the whole point of taking `a` and `b` by value is to *avoid* copying.